# How can i get the response value from card buttons using hero card

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot

I'm building a chat bot for products. I have a long list of products (each product display as card with the name only). I want the user to choose from the list which works fine but my issue is saving the data when the user is clicking on the product card. I don't see the data, any idea?

```
var inMemoryStorage = new builder.MemoryBotStorage();

var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
    session.replaceDialog('chooseProduct');

}).set('storage', inMemoryStorage);


bot.dialog("chooseProduct",

(session)  => {
    var card = new builder.HeroCard(session)
    .title('Hey there!')
    .subtitle("What would you like to buy?")
        .buttons([
            builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "iPhone6-16GB", "iPhone6"),
            builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "iPhone6-32GB", "iPhone6"),
            builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "iPhone6-64GB", "iPhone6"),
            builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "iPhone6-128GB", "iPhone6"),
            builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "iPhone7-16GB", "iPhone6"),
            builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "iPhone7-32GB", "iPhone6"),
            builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "iPhone7-64GB", "iPhone6"),
            builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "iPhone7-128GB", "iPhone6"),

        ]);
    var msg = new builder.Message(session)
        .addAttachment(card)
        .inputHint(builder.InputHint.acceptingInput);
    session.send(msg).endDialog();
}

).triggerAction({matches: /Help|Hi|hi|Hey|menu|Menu/g});

bot.dialog('selectedProduct, 
    (session,results)=>{
        // I'm trying to save the data
        var selectedIphone = results.response.entity // Sadly this does not store it, but this is what I'm trying to get
    }    
).triggerAction({matches: /iPhone/g});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just get the message text from the response with 'session.message.text'.

```
bot.dialog('selectedProduct', 
     (session)=>{
        // I'm trying to save the data
        var selectedIphone = session.message.text;
    }    
).triggerAction({matches: /iPhone/g});
```

For a more universal solution, have a look at the middleware capabilities illustrated here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/capability-middlewareLogging/app.js

Comment: Thank you! that's exactly what I was looking for